# Parse Date from Array - JS

Tags: javascript

I have an array with a date. When I parse it, the month increases by 1. How can I fix it?

```js
var data = [{
  name: 'Arun',
  date: [2019, 4, 9, 14, 55, 28, 897778]
}, {
  name: 'Manohar',
  date: [2019, 4, 3, 22, 43, 54, 894553]
}]

data.forEach((item) => {
  item.date.pop()
  item.date = new Date(...item.date).toLocaleString('en-US')
});

console.log(data)
```

I want the month as April and not May. Please advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters) suggests, the `monthIndex` would start at 0, rather than 1. So you need to manually subtract 1.

```
data.forEach((item) => {
  item.date.pop()
  item.date[1]--
  item.date = new Date(...item.date).toLocaleString('en-US')
});
```

Comment: How to reduce the month value in the loop I have?

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate the help. Just curious whether this Will convert from January 2019 to December 2018?

Comment: Yes, it will. But considering the source of your data should only be returning months between 1 and 12, the `monthIndex` will only ever be between `0` and `11`. You could add a check if you wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

The month is represented by a value from 0 to 11, 4 is the fifth month, it corresponds to May, you just need to decrease it by 1.

Comment: How to reduce the month value in the loop I have?